# Select2 Multi-select Strange Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-select2, marionette

When the page loads initially the placeholder cannot be seen and there is a strange circle (I think it's related to the search feature in Select2) in the bottom right hand corner which is overlaying the placeholder.

[image: Initial Page Load]

Then, as an option is selected from the Select2 dropdown, the option shows up, but the entire area is pushed down due to that circle overlay.

[image: First Selection]

If I clear the selections, the place holder shows up, but the circle is still there.

My application uses Backbone and Marionette

Here is the code I'm using in my .js file (I've played with the `minimumResultsForSearch` option but haven't had any luck).

```
this.$el.find("#categorySelect").select2({
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    placeholder: "Categories"
})
```

Here is the code I'm using in my .tpl file

```
<select id="categorySelect" name="Categories" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
    <% for(category in categories){ %>
        <option value="<%=categories[category].title%>"
        <% if (categories[category].active == true) { %>
            selected
        <%}%>
        >
        <%=categories[category].title%></option>
    <% }; %>
</select>
```

Comment: This likely has something to do with CSS than JS unless there are JavaScript errors. Please share a [mcve]

Comment: I tried setting up a(n) MCV, but I'm having some trouble getting select2 to source in properly. Any chance you/someone could take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/az5dksyz/

Answer (score 1):

Your order of scripts is incorrect, you need to load jQuery before you use it.

Also you're trying to initialize select2 on elements that does not exist yet, i.e before actually rendering the view.

And there are somethings that doesn't make any sense like

`this.$el.html(_.extend(this.template(modelJSON)));`
Why would you try to extend an HTML string?

or

```
$(function(select2) {
   App.start(select2);
});
```

What is passing `select2` as first argument to jQuery ready event handler?

Please try to understand the code you are writing, and why you're writing it.

Fixing all such issues gives something like this http://jsfiddle.net/az5dksyz/2/.

Also it's a good idea to not use `id` in template strings because they could be rendered multiple times, and to not use inline style rules in them.

Comment: Thanks for helping me set up the MCV. At least now I can tell there is likely something wonky somewhere in the CSS.